# How to convert ExecutedRoutedEventArgs to RoutedEventArgs?

Tags: c#, wpf

In XAML I have a ListBox MenuItem that for its Click="" method I want to reuse an existing method but which is already declared with (object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) parameters.

Using it as so gives the following error:
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs' to 'System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs'

Is it possible to convert ExecutedRoutedEventArgs to RoutedEventArgs for it to work? or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the signature of the event delegate - a click event handler only accepts a `RoutedEventArgs` and nothing else - but you can move the code from the existing event handler into a method that you can call from any event handlers, e.g.:

```
private void OnClick(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    YourMethod();
}

private void OnClick1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    YourMethod();
}

private void YourMethod()
{
    //your common logic...
}
```